# Validación de contenido en hoja de cálculo de Google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

¿Alguien sabe como validar si una spreadsheet ya fue copiada en una spreadsheet diferente?

Tengo este código para copiar distintas spreadsheet que se encuentran en una misma carpeta pero ahora lo que necesito es saber si esa spreadsheet ya fue copiada para que ya no se vuelva a copiar y no se si se puede actualizar allí mismo

```
function mergeSheets() {
  /* Retrieve the desired folder */
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("All Reports").next();

  /* Get all spreadsheets that resided on that folder */
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");

  /* Create the new spreadsheet that you store other sheets */  
  var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("157dEC204oGa8Jq5B7nUUQfxAk0GLXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

  /* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {

    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();

    /* Open the spreadsheet */
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());

    /* Get all its sheets */
    for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) {
      /* Copy the sheet to the new merged Spread Sheet */
        spreadSheet.getSheets()[y].copyTo(newSpreadSheet);
    }
  }      
}
```

Comment: Usa el hash (función resumen) del archivo y lo guardas; antes de copiar uno nuevo lo calculas y revisas que no haya sido guardado. Eso te ayuda además para sobreescribir los que hayan sido actualizados.

Comment: Pero y eso funciona si necesito que se haga automático?

Comment: Si, justamente, consulta en la ayuda como invocar la función de resumen la ejecutas dentro del ciclo for antes de copiar y "lees" el valor guardado, si no existe, ejecutas la copia y registras el valor. Cuando digo lees y copias me refiero a que el script lo hace.

Comment: El término en inglés es `spreadsheet` no `spreadSheet`

Comment: @quevedo Ni Google Apps Script ni Google Drive cuentan con una función llamada `hash`, de hecho el término es ambiguo por lo que sería bueno que fueras específico sobre cómo buscar la función resumen como indicar al menos la página de inicio de la ayuda a la que te refieres.

Comment: Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que los archivos de los editores de G Suite, incluyendo las hojas de cálculo de Google, son un tipo de archivo especial el cual a diferencia de otros archivos no se encuentra documentado así que Google puede cambiar el formato en cualquier momento y sin previo aviso.

Comment: @ruben Gracias por la indicación. La sugerencia apunta a que si se desea copiar masivamente archivos se necesita validar preexistencia y las funciones resumen lo resuelven. Si un entorno no cuenta con ellas de modo explícito se pueden invocar vía shell, execute o similares dependiendo de la naturaleza del lenguaje. Si aún así no se pudiera, consultando algoritmos de función resumen se puede programar una para el caso. No se, a ciencia cierta si G suite admita programarlas.

Comment: @quevedo¿alguna vez has usado las hojas de cálculo de Google?

Comment: @ruben Si, pero nunca me he visto en la necesidad de copiarlas en masa.

Comment: Bien. Qué tal si escribes una respuesta explicando cómo se usaría la función resumen en el caso de la AP. Me parece que podria ser en casi cualquier lenguaje que pueda trabajar con Google Sheets API. Dependiendo de cómo pienses hacerlo también podría requerirse la API de Google Drive.

Answer (score 2):

Resumen

Crea una lista de los id de las hojas de cálculo que han sido combinadas y antes de hacer 
una nueva combinación verifica que el id de la hoja de cálculo a combinar no se encuentre listada.

Explicación

Google Drive API V3 cuenta con el recurso [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) el cual a su vez cuenta con la función `md5checksum` pero esta sólo está disponible para archivos binarios como archivos con extensiones PDF, PNG, etc. pero no para archivos de los Editores de Documentos de G Suite como las hojas de cálculo de Google, si bien es posible implementar un algoritmo para hacer algo equivalente me parece que con llevar un registro de los id de las hojas de cálculo importadas es suficiente.

Implementación de la idea sugerida

Existen muchas formas de hacer esto, quizás la más sencilla es la siguiente

1. Agrega una hoja para llevar la lista de id. Para efectos del ejemplo incluido abajo le llamaremos `Registro`.
2. (opcional) Elimina la columna B y siguientes con la finalidad de "ahorrar" celdas ya que la hoja de cálculo de Google tiene un límite de 5 millones de celdas.
3. Crea una función de validación que te devuelva `true` o `false`. Para efectos del ejemplo mostrado mas abajo le llamaremos `isMerged`.
4. Edita tu código para agregar una sentencia `if` y dentro de los bloques de esta sentencia pon la parte que hace la combinación de tal forma que si se ha encontrado el id no se ejecute y si se ha encontrado no se ejecute.
5. En la edición del código incluye el agregar el id de la hoja de cálculo recién combinada.

Por ejemplo, esta parte del código podría verse de la siguiente forma:

```
if(!isMerged(sheet.getId()){
  for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) {
     /* Copy the sheet to the new merged Spread Sheet */
     spreadSheet.getSheets()[y].copyTo(newSpreadSheet);
  }
 newSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Registro').appendRow([sheet.getId()])
}
```